# How do I disable button until another button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have a project on vb.net2010 contains 3 buttons:
1. Save
2. Search
3. Update
I want to disable update button untill when you press the search button.
How can I programmatically?
thank you

Comment: `someButton.Enabled = False` ?

Comment: Set its `Enabled` property to `False`. When you want to enable it, set the `Enabled` property to `True`.

Comment: someButton.Enabled = False this is not worked for me

Comment: i think its like this 
if
btn_search.Enabled = True  Then
        Else
            btn_search.Enabled = True
        End If

Comment: `this is not worked for me` is not very helpful

Comment: i have search button and update button and i want to disable update button until search button is clicked.
how i can do that problematically.

Comment: So go ahead and disable it. You can do that in the designer, or in the form's Load event handler, or wherever you need to. Set the update button's `Enabled` property to `True` when you want to enable it (presumably in the search button's Click event handler. If you don't know how to do that, I suggest looking for a tutorial on programming for Windows Forms.

Comment: I understand enabling  and disabling  but I can not put this condition to my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Form called `Form1` with three buttons: `SaveButton`, `SearchButton`, `UpdateButton`, put this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.UpdateButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
        Me.UpdateButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: correct but the PO wanted to enable/disbale the `UpdateButton`

Answer (score -4):

```
Update_button.Enabled = false

If Search_button.event = click then
 Update_button.Enable = True

Else Update_button.Enabled = false
EndIf
```

Comment: No. The property is called `Enabled`, not Enable. And `If searchbutn.Click Then` will not compile. The statement `updatebutn.Enabled = True` needs to be inside the update button's Click event handler

Comment: I wish Ahmed Mohammed could provide a sample of his code. if will make things easier.

Comment: `Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As system.Object, ByVal e As system.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
btn_update.Enabled = False

        If btn_search.Click Then btn_update.Enabled = True
        End If
End Sub`
If btn_search.Click is not worked for me

Comment: @MIGHTY_TEFLON this the code

Comment: @MIGHTY_TEFLON what language is this?

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Search_Button.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
        Me.SaveButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: So somehow you have pasted basically my answer, in a comment, with two different names for the button, one of which incidentally is SearchButton, which I had mistakenly used and have since fixed in my answer. Whew

Comment: What is this even? `if searchbutn.click`

Comment: `If Search_button.event = click` ?

Comment: Why do you even keep updating this post? In .NET there is no such thing as a `Button.event` property. I'd recommend you test your code before you post it in an answer.